# Why java strings are not saved as UTF-8 in MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding

```
message = new String(("round " + id).getBytes("UTF-8"));

conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + db + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&"
              + "user=" + login + "&password=" + password);
```

When I make an insert into the database which encoding is `UTF-8 CI`, get  something like this `�������������������� 179`, the java file encoding is utf-8, what I'am doing wrong?

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, MySQL comes with a list of predefined system variables. If you want to list them, you can open the MySQL prompt and type:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | latin1                     |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

As shown, MySQL's default encoding is `latin1`. In order to change it, you need to edit a bit your **my.cnf** file and add the following lines:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

When you configure the **my.cnf** file and restart the MySQL server, you'll note the difference.

**Edit**:
You can set the encoding for the JDBC's `DriverManager` like this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + db + "?useUnicode=true&"
              + "user=" + login + "&password=" + password + "&characterEncoding=utf8");
```

Comment: changed all that but still I'am getting that bad encoded string

Comment: Did you restart the MySQL server ?

Comment: also that happens only when I insert it from java code, if I insert a string from phpmyadmin for example, its all okay, I've noticed that it only happens with cyrillic letters, but why that happens if the encoding is utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Besides set connection string in java jdbc,An alternative way to change mysql charset:

1) specify utf8 when creating database and table

```
    //database
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS databasename 
    default charset utf8
    COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

    //table
    CREATE TABLE  `Extenics`.`BE_headset` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2) or alter it after creating(I don't encourage this)

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name

    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]

    [[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]
```

see [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html) for more help.

Comment: try restart your mysql service.

Comment: mysqld restart, nothing changed

Comment: I suggest 1)create a temporary database and table using utf8,do insert test(use SQL sentence),see what happen. 2)my jdbc like [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mapping?characterSetResults=UTF-8&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=yes] work,check your url again.

Comment: the database and tables are fully utf-8, I've added to the url characterSetResults=UTF-8, but that doesn't helped, I've did all what I've known...