# Java won't write UTF8 characters in MySQL through a JNDI datasource

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have configured JNDI to access a MySQL database with the UTF-8 server charset.
My JNDI URL in Tomcat's context file is `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/my_db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"`
The database server, the database and its table are all set to utf-8 using the instructions in this site.

By debugging the JDBC connection it appears to use UTF-8.
However an e grave character is written in the database as 0x C3 83 C2 A8.
Clearly, the UTF-8 string for e grave, which is 0x C3 A8 has been misinterpreted by the server as Latin1 and 0xC3 in Latin-1 is 0xC3 83 in UTF-8, and similarly 0xA8 in Latin-1 is 0xC2 A8 in UTF-8.

If the database is properly configured as per [Why java strings are not saved as UTF-8 in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092007/why-java-strings-are-not-saved-as-utf-8-in-mysql)
why is the server converting the input UTF-8 string from the driver into Latin-1 and then back into UTF-8 (the encoding for the database and table I am using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the source.

If you had that `è` from some text, properties or java source then you could try to substitute it with `\u00e8`.

Encoding mismatch between editor (UTF-8) and javac compiler (maybe Windows-1252 aka  Windows Latin-1).

A .properties must be in ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1), if UTF-8 you would get such a behaviour.

If data entry, and a web application, the entire chain must be correct. The form posts in UTF-8, the request parameters are taken as HTTP default, ISO-8859-1. Again the error would show.

---

Assuming it is the properties file. Which is considered by Java SE to be in ISO-8859-1, but you wrote UTF-8:

An ad-hoc hack would be:

```
String s = bundle.getString("somekey");
byte[] utf8Bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
s = new String(utf8Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Better would be converting to ASCII resp. ISO-8859-1 using the command-line:

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 INPUT.properties OUTPUT.properties
```

Reversal to UTF-8 would function as follows:

```
native2ascii -reverse -encoding UTF-8 INPUT.properties OUTPUT.properties
```

Instead of command-line ant or maven can do it too.

Comment: Yes, doing the replacement you suggest makes it work. Which makes me wonder, suppose I have a properties file most probably in ISO-8859-1, how do I detect its encoding and generate a String that I feed to my PreparedStatement?

Comment: So it is the .properties. The java standard for .properties is hard set to ISO-8859-1. For other Unicode characters, one should use the `\uXXXX` escaping. Fortunately some IDEs like NetBeans, allows editing with normal characters, and saving it u-escaped. There are standalone properties editors too. - The only other encoding making sense would be UTF-8, and I have seen switching the encoding in code (ugly as not main-stream IMHO) and u-escaping as last phase in copying source files to the target directory. I'll extend the answer

Comment: It is going to be a pain if the properties file is translated by an external company and handed back to us in an Excel. The Russian or Asian language strings will have to be copied one by one and escaped with \uXXXX. I will mark your post as the answer.

Comment: For translation it really makes sense to spend time on the "main dictionary" - collecting all strings, removing double texts, disambiguising (verb or noun, ...), extracting a glossary. This improves quality, consistency, and esp. crucial understandability. It saves money. XML (docbook, xliff, tmx) is ideal. Excel/Word can be painful, but the xlsx, docx are in fact zips with XML; Word being easy to process in java. The best experience was with docbook, XMLSpy as editor, and a table with text, title, tooltip, help text, comment. Using XSLT to extract an XML for the i18n.